# A general proof of showing the existence of infinitely many solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In my research, I came across these 2 simultaneous equations given by
$$2r^4-12r^2s^2+2s^4=g^3-3gh^2$$
and
$$8r^3s-8rs^3=3g^2h-h^3\,.$$

Upon solving these two equations simultaneously using SAGEMATH in which the range of the variables $r,s,g$, and $h$ restricted from $-1500$ until $1500$, infinitely many solutions were obtained given by

```
(r,s,g,h)=
(±13,±9,14,-48),(±13,∓9,14,48),(±9,±13,14,48),(±9,∓13,14,- 48), 
(±55,±37,238,240),(±55,∓37,238,- 240),(±37,±55,238,-240),(±37,∓55,238,240), 
(±8,±44,-56,192 ),(±8,∓44,-56,-192),(±44,±8,-56,-192),(±44,∓8,-56,192), 
(±99,±5,-322,480),(±99,∓5,-322,-480),(±5,±99,-322,-480),(±5,∓99,-322,480), 
(±104,±72,224,-768),(±104,∓72,224,768),(±72,±104,224,768),(±72,∓104,224,-768), 
(±161,±73,1054,672),(±161,∓73,1054,-672),(±73,±161,1054,-672),
 (±73,∓161,1054,672)}
```

But these are just numerical results. My concern: is there a better way of showing that infinitely many solutions do exist theoretically. Or perhaps show the general form of solutions obtained above. I have tried looking for patterns of the solutions for each variable as well as in terms of congruences, but they do not seem to portray a specific pattern, instead, they just appear randomly. Any idea of how to work around this, please.

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your equations are hard to read.  Do you mean, e.g., $(2r^4-12r^2)\times(s^2+2s^4)$?  Something else?

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions?

Comment: @lulu sorry I have edited that.. there was an unnecessary space in between.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes definitely integral solutions only. like the one I have computed above.

Comment: Your attempt to fix those unreadable formulas by tweaking the spacing is ineffective. Please read the [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial and then use it to edit your formulas so that they are actually readable.

Comment: You can combine the two equations to get $$2(r+is)^4 = (g + ih)^3\,.$$ What do you know about Gaussian integers?

Comment: With $r,s,g,h$ restricted to integers between $-1500$ and $1500$, there are only *finitely many* such quadruples to begin with. The set produced by SageMath is of course *finite* as well (it has $96$ elements). So no, SageMath did not obtain infinitely many solutions and this does *not* show that infinitely many solutions exist.

Comment: @daniel yes this problem is actually related to Gaussian integers. And i know quite a lot on Gaussian integers. I am impressed that you manage to crack that out.

Comment: @christoph yes i agree with you. Because at the moment I don't even know if solutions do exist outside this interval or not.

Comment: Please include context like this being related to Gaussian integers and where the problem came up in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your equations is of the form: $2(r+is)^4=(g+ih)^3$ which is really an equation of the type $2u^4=v^3$ in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$. For example (your smallest example):

$$2(\pm 13\pm 9i)^4=(14-48i)^3$$

It is well known that the ring $\mathbb Z[i]$ supports unique factorisation into Gaussian primes which are of one of the form:

- $1+i$, which is the same as $1-i$ up to association,
- $a+bi$ with $a^2+b^2=p$ - prime of the form $4k+1$,
- $p\in\mathbb N$ - prime of the form $4k+3$.

Obviously, as $2=-i(1+i)^2$, if, say $(1+i)^k$ is a factor of $u$, with multiplicity $k$, it will be the factor of $v^3$ with multiplicity $2+4k$, which must be divisible by $3$, which implies $k\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

For any other prime $p$ (of the second or third kind), if it is a factor of $u$ with multiplicity $k$, then it is a factor of $v^3$ with multiplicity $4k$, so $3\mid k$.

Thus, the "basic" solution should be the one where $u$ and $v$ have no other factors than necessary, i.e. $u\sim 1+i$ and $v\sim (1+i)^2$. This is satisfied with:

$$u_0=1+i$$
$$v_0=-2$$

In other words, $(r,s,g,h)=(1,1,-2,0)$.

You can then make any solution by picking any Gaussian integer $w$ and setting $u=u_0w^3$ and $v=v_0w^4$ (all the other prime factors of $u$, including additional instances of $1+i$, will have multiplicity divisible by $3$ - so let's collect the "cube root" as $w$ etc. etc.) For example, take $w$ to be the prime $w=1+2i$ ($2^2+1^2=5$ - prime of the form $4k+1$), and then:

$$u=(1+i)(1+2i)^3=-9-13i$$
$$v=-2(1+2i)^4=14+48i$$

which is one of your first solutions. As you can pick $w$ in infinitely many ways, you end up with infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Wow this is great explanation. Thank you so much for showing me this.. i never knew that I could use Gaussian primes to show this.. all this while I have been working on r, s, g, h without putting them in Gaussian integer terms.. thank you so much.. i really appreciate this..

Comment: I have not written the proof with full rigour, but I hope you will be able to fill in the gaps and show that these formulas ($u=u_0w^3, v=v_0w^4$ for $w\in\mathbb Z[i]$) give all solutions. (I did not go into the analysis of the units, but I think it will turn out to be fairly trivial.)

Comment: Yes sure. I am writing down the proof to make sure i really understand it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @stiking bishop Hi. I have a couple of questions regarding the proving. By using basic Gaussian primes, we can generate solutions to the equation $2u^4 = v^3$ if we let $w=a+bi$ to be Gaussian primes of the type $a^2+b^2=p$, where p is a usual prime number. There are infinitely many primes where $p\equiv1(mod 4)$. This leads to infinitely many such solutions. My concern is how about those Gaussian numbers $w = a + bi$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = n$. Many such $n$ exist where their prime power decompositions do not contain a prime congruent to 3 mod 4 to an odd power. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @shahrinaismail Looking back at my proof - it seems that the exact form of primes in $\mathbb Z[i]$ doesn't really help - as long as you know how to decompose $2$. The only thing we use is unique decomposition into primes.

Comment: can you help me further explain please. I am sorry that I am having trouble understanding the concept of what happens if I encounter $$a^2+b^2=n$$ and n is not a prime. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @shahrinaismail In my proof, $w$ can be *any* Gaussian complex number. Provided $(u_0, v_0)$ is a solution to $2u^4=v^3$, so is $(u_0w^3, v_0w^4)$. (You just get the additional factor $w^{12}$)